# How to get a specific viewable string on page through Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, capybara, html-parsing, nokogiri

Currently, I am able to parse a website with Nokogiri and grab specific elements from pages. However, I need to be able to grab a specific string such as "Out of stock" that is visible to the user:

```
page.text.match('Out of stock')
```

That works fine for grabbing the correct string and returning true or false if the string is or isn't there, however, some links like the following, return true even if the item is not out of stock because that specific string is hidden in a script tag on the page:

```
https://www.walmart.com/ip/Funyuns-Onion-Flavored-Rings-6-oz/36915849?athcpid=36915849&athpgid=athenaItemPage&athcgid=null&athznid=PWSFM&athieid=v0&athstid=CS020&athguid=ba634528-888-172187cc96a580&athancid=null&athena=true
```

I am looking for a way so that that string is pulled if and only if it is visible to users so the above should return false for matching the "Out of stock" string, while the link below should return true (at time of posting), because the item is actually out of stock.

```
https://www.walmart.com/ip/4-Pack-Chesters-Flamin-Hot-Popcorn-4-25-oz/737202470?selected=true
```

I am also aware that I could grab the specific tag that contains the string, but I need to monitor hundreds of websites so the solution has to be a broad search for a visible string.

Comment: page scraping is notoriously unreliable, particularly when you are trying to make it work over hundreds of websites. As a start, you might try a regex search that includes the preceding `>` and following `<` characters. But while it may help, this is not foolproof by any means. I would also look at Capybara... it may not be particularly performant but it will likely be more reliable.

Comment: Also "visible" is sometimes hard to specify. If it's in a script, it's obviously not visible. If it has style="display: none", then it's also probably not visible. However, what if it's white on a white background. What if it's behind something else, what if it's positioned out of the page, what if it's font size is microscopic?

Comment: You have to do something more specific and accurate than searching for a short text string; It's way too easily fooled. When working with hundreds of sites the odds are good you'll have to write hundreds of spiders because every site codes pages differently. Take advantage of REST or API calls to their site whenever possible instead because the data you get will be much more easily processed and be more reliable.

Comment: And if there is no API you should really be asking yourself if what you are doing violates a TOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: we can use `xpath` syntax for this with more specific.

long story:
I strongly recommend to put more specific with css-classes, coz, in some of the cases we can get this text not only in "script tag" but also by media query or in item-preview blocks or whatever, and handle common cases as big chunks, but not to force to use one specific solution for all cases, in case of unexpected behavior

so we need to be more specific and use the "target-tags" to handle it, for example:

```
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.html).xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'prod-PriceSection')]//*[contains(@class, 'prod-ProductOffer-oosMsg')]").text
"Out of stock"
```

so, "to monitor hundreds of websites" we can going with this approach:

```
xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'PriceSection')]").text
```

or even better to use something like this to be sure that element is surly visible:

```
page.all("//body//*[contains(text(), 'Out of stock')]", visible: true).count
# => 1
```

if the usage of one more request (in previous solution) by Capybara may become a problem, we can follow with this solution, it's much faster:

```
xpath("//body//*[not(self::script) and contains(text(), 'Out of stock')]").count
```

I hope it's help

Comment: This won't work well if a site uses CSS or DHTML to programmatically hide or display an "Out of stock" string. Nokogiri isn't aware of the state of a page, it only knows what the markup contains. Use `nokogiri` at the command-line to load the page and look in the DOM; It only works on the static page.

Comment: Excellent. That bottom example worked perfectly. Thank you so much!